# How do I separate these data from each other

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda, data-science, data-cleaning

I have a data set whereby the data in ever cell is mixed up with the column name in each cell as illustrated below:

```
Gender
“Gender”:”male”
“Gender”:”female”
“Gender”:”male”
“Gender”:”female”
```

I am in the process of cleaning it via anaconda and I have tried all but to no avail. I want it to look as illustrated below:

```
Gender
Male
Female
Male
Female
```

Comment: can you provide the content of you dataset as dictionary? assuming the dataframe is named `df`, run `df.to_dict()`

Comment: Pls tell us the effort you are already making so that we can help you improve it

Answer (score -2):

Considering your question. I have recreated the `dataframe` like this below,

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Gender":['“Gender”:”male”',
 '“Gender”:”female”',
 '“Gender”:”male”',
 '“Gender”:”female”']})
```

So, the `DataFrame` looks like this below,

```
              Gender
0    “Gender”:”male”
1  “Gender”:”female”
2    “Gender”:”male”
3  “Gender”:”female”
```

Here is the code that can solve the issue

```
for i in df.columns:
    df[i] = [j.replace("”",'').split(":")[-1].capitalize() for j in df[i]]
```

Output `df`:

```
   Gender
0    Male
1  Female
2    Male
3  Female
```

Answer (score -2):

You can make use of Pandas Apply function like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Gender":['“Gender”:”male”','“Gender”:”female”','“Gender”:”male”','“Gender”:”female”'])

def cln(st):
 me = st.split(":")
 return me[1] 

df["Gender"].apply(lambda val: cln(val))
```

Answer (score -2):

The data has some weird quote character so you'll need to do some massaging to make it clean. You can simple use the [`str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html) call on the Series object to work directly with the string values.

```
df.Gender.str.replace(r'”|“', '', regex=True)\
         .str.split(":", expand=True)[1]\
         .str.capitalize()

0      Male
1    Female
2      Male
3    Female
```